# Logitech SetPoint Alternative for MX Revolution on Windows

Tags: drivers, software-rec, logitech-mouse

Is there a software alternative out there for Logitech SetPoint on Windows (7)? Specifically for the Logitech MX Revolution Mouse. The required features are just key mappings and configuration of the of the mouse wheel mode (this is my main goal).

The problem I have with the SetPoint software is that is a) slow b) big and c) from time to time has problems with detecting the mouse after standby.

Comment: Check [this thread](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-Software/My-Alternative-to-setpoint/m-p/124333) on the logitech forums which points to [zwda](http://fzwte.net/site/ZWDA_Home) which supports `logitech MX Revolution

    Handle all the buttons (except the search button since it's a composite device) and the scroll wheel. `

Comment: +1 for zwda. A bit painful to set up, but an amazing driver. Lets you assign keystrokes, clicks, scripts whatever to any of the buttons, and even create combinations of buttons, or conditional buttons - eg. I have it set up so that if the thumb button is down scrolling controls the volume of my sound. Logitech should hire this guy and get him to write their drivers.

Comment: Can someone point to a download for ZWDA? All links seem to go to a dead end.

Comment: Could not find it anywhere, I'd contact http://zewaren.net/, seems that's the author. There is also the Google code project https://code.google.com/p/zwda/, but it requires you to build it yourself from source code. Considered the age and that it is abondomed, the Logitech software is probably the best bet. My original problem of the post is actually solved by now (no more standby issues). It's still slow and big, but so is newer hardware =)

Answer (score 4):

I had that issue a while back on another PC, setpoint works fine on my current notebook however.

What I did, uninstall setpoint and installed [Microsofts Intellipoint software](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/1423-microsoft-intellipoint.html), and installed it, found a compatible MS mouse model that worked with my Logitech buttons and functions and selected that MS model during Install during setup of the software. I think you can change the model after install if you did not select one that did not quite match during setup.

Then to further customize my buttons, [I installed X-Mouse](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm)

x-mouse will not work with generic windows mouse driver, as it only intercepts the mouse click, and generic mouse driver will not have drivers for anything other than right and left click, the reason I used intellipoint.

I have not used intellipoint in a while, the older versions did not care what brand of mouse you had, if the newer versions do, look for an older version of intellipoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but AFAIK Microsoft has no support for the different modes of the mouse wheel like Logitech does (when spinning the wheel fast, it goes into a mode where there is no click after a turn and behaves more like a fly wheel). So I don't think this will be configurable with the Intellipoint software.

Comment: Then I guess you have to live with setpoint bloatware.

Answer (score 4):

I found this software: [uberOptions](http://uberoptions.net/)

> uberOptions: Enable all options on all buttons in SetPoint.

It is an add-on for SetPoint which enables extra functionalities